# place text next to image html to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: html, image, itext, xmlworker

I am converting html to pdf using itextsharp. I have to place text next to the image not below the image. In html I am able to place text next to image but in pdf the text line starts after image

Please help.

Comment: HTML parsing support in iTextSharp is very limited depending on how you do it. If you provide a code sample we might be able to help you more. Otherwise the simple solution is to just use an HTML table.

Answer (score 10):

Since you mention HTML, you understand *block* and *inline* display, right? By analogy, iTextSharp's default `Image` display is *block*. To *inline* `Image` objects you need to:

1. Add images to `Chunk` object(s)
2. Add text in `Phrase` object(s)
3. Then add those object to a `Paragraph` object

Something like this:

```
Image image = Image.GetInstance(imagePath);  
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Add(new Phrase("Text next to the image "));
p.Add(new Chunk(image, 0, 0));
p.Add(new Phrase(" and text after the image.")); 
document.Add(p);
```

Replace `imagePath` above with the physical path to your image

Comment: but i am converting the pdf directly from html image tag using

Comment: i am using HTmlWorker.ParseToList metod to pasre the html <img src="imageurl"> tag.then how to do it in code behind logic.

Comment: Use [XmlWorker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html). Then you don't have the block/inline problem with regard to images; images are displayed **inline** by default. But you **must** setup an `ImageProvider` to account for: [1] relative image URL(s), [2] the way iText[Sharp] handles image sizing. See the documentation providing in the link at the start of **this** commment.

Comment: The 4th line of the snippet should be: `p.add(new Chunk(image,0,0,true));` a fourth boolean param is required, otherwise overload resolution will fail trying to cast image object to a IDrawInterface

Answer (score 2):

You can try these following code sample.

```
Image jpg = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/Sunset.jpg");
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Suspendisse blandit blandit turpis. Nam in lectus ut dolor consectetuer bibendum. Morbi neque ipsum, laoreet id; dignissim et, viverra id, mauris. Nulla mauris elit, consectetuer sit amet, accumsan eget, congue ac, libero. Vivamus suscipit. Nunc dignissim consectetuer lectus. Fusce elit nisi; commodo non, facilisis quis, hendrerit eu, dolor? Suspendisse eleifend nisi ut magna. Phasellus id lectus! Vivamus laoreet enim et dolor. Integer arcu mauris, ultricies vel, porta quis, venenatis at, libero. Donec nibh est, adipiscing et, ullamcorper vitae, placerat at, diam. Integer ac turpis vel ligula rutrum auctor! Morbi egestas erat sit amet diam. Ut ut ipsum? Aliquam non sem. Nulla risus eros, mollis quis, blandit ut; luctus eget, urna. Vestibulum vestibulum dapibus erat. Proin egestas leo a metus?");
paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
jpg.ScaleToFit(250f, 250f);
jpg.Alignment = Image.TEXTWRAP | Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;
jpg.IndentationLeft = 9f;
jpg.SpacingAfter = 9f;
jpg.BorderWidthTop = 36f;
jpg.BorderColorTop = Color.WHITE;
doc.Add(jpg);
doc.Add(paragraph);
```

source : http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images

By Mikesdotnetting