# place image and text side bu side in PDF

Tags: itext

I am using itextsharp to generate pdf.I have to place image and text side by side .
I tried doing this using table but it is not working.[image]

this is what i am getting.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A similar, but not exact, question was asked the previous day. [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129866/place-text-next-to-image-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp/9131447#9131447) will work for you.