# itextsharp and image rotation

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I have an image that I am inserting into a pdf file that I am creating with iTextSharp and asp.net. The image that I have added is a barcode that I need to rotate so that it is portrait instead of landscape on the page. Is there any way to do this with iTextSharp.

Comment: `jpg.Rotation = (float)Math.PI / 2;jpg.RotationDegrees = 90f;` further http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images

Comment: `img.setRotationDegrees(90);`

Comment: thanks nishant Solanki this work to rotate the image. My next question is can I have the text that I want to add as well to the page next to the image is there any way to do this?

Comment: please look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129866/place-text-next-to-image-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: Hi @NishantSolanki If you combine your two comments in an answer, we can upvote it and as such contribute to your SO reputation.

Comment: Thanks. I also kept my promise ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check below code to rotate image using iTextSharp

```
image.setRotationDegrees(90); // this will rotate the image to 90 degree clockwise
```

to add text besides image you can use below code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129866/place-text-next-to-image-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)

```
Image image = Image.GetInstance(imagePath);  
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Add(new Phrase("Text next to the image "));
p.Add(new Chunk(image, 0, 0));
p.Add(new Phrase(" and text after the image.")); 
document.Add(p);
```