# Add image and text in one line itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

Below code is adding text and image in separate lines. How can I display them in one line?

```
pdfDoc.Add(image)
pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(text))
```

Comment: one way to do this is [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129866/place-text-next-to-image-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp#9131447).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found, using `Chunk()`:

```
Dim p As New Paragraph()
p.Add(New Chunk(image, 0, 0))
p.Add(text)
document.Add(p)
```